# using node Q to update object values

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I have an object with certain keys which need to be updated. The updates are through a function (gets info from a database) and returns a promise. The original object has many keys and only some will need updating.

```
// mocked response for demonstration
// the call01 function returns an array that make_obj function uses.
// the make_obj function returns an object like var obj.
// the get_data expects an array of ints and returns an array of strings like ['cat', 'dog', 'boat']


var obj = {'key1': {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,4], 'c': [5,6,7]}, 'key2': {'a': [5,4,5], 'b': [9,8,9], 'c': [1,9,5]}}
var _ = require('lodash');


function updater(obj) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    _.forIn(obj, function(v,k) {
        get_data(v.a)
            .then(function(words) {
                v.a = words;
            });

        get_data(v.b)
            .then(function(words) {
                v.b = words;
            });
        deferred.resolve(obj);
    });

    return deferred.promise;

// call01 returns a promise
call01(some_val)
    .then(make_obj)
    .then(updater)
    .then(console.log)
```

I am expecting to see the something like this (granted i'm making up the values here):

```
{'key1': {'a': ['cat', 'dog', 'boat'], 'b': ['dog', 'boat', 'chair'] , 'c': [5,7,8]}, 'key2': {'a': ['spoon', 'chair', 'spoon'], 'b': ['tree', 'bird', 'tree'], 'c': [1,9,5]}}
```

I know that I may need to have a Q.all or Q.allSettled to aggregate the promises but I cannot get it to work.

This is what I tried with Q.all.  What isn't working is that the I could not figure out how to map the results from var promises back to the obj to update the values.

```
function updater(obj) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    // this is only making an array of get_data from el.a
    var promise_arr1 = _.map(obj, function(el){
        return get_data(el.a);    
    });

    // this is only making an array of get_data from el.b
    var promise_arr2 = _.map(obj, function(el){
        return get_data(el.b);
    });

    // I know this is not the right way to do it. the result flattened arr has no mapping back to the original obj. I wasn't sure how to make the update to obj.
    Q.all(_.flatten(promise_arr1, promise_arr2))
        .then(deferred.resolve)


    return deferred.promise;
```

I even thought about using async instead of q. I saw that async has a async.eachSeries but I didn't give it a full try yet.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Your loops are mixed up. If you're object's layout is really like `obj`, then you want to `_.forIn` over `obj.key1` and over `obj.key2`, not the other way round.

Comment: What argument does `getData` expect - the array `[1,2,3]` or a single number?

Comment: `call01()` needs to return a *promise for* an array…

Comment: Please show us what you tried with `Q.all`, and what you'd think your code would look like with `async.js` (only so that we understand what you want and can show you how promises are superior :-)

Comment: The loops are still not matching your `obj`. Given the layout you posted, it would need to be `promise_arr1 = _.map(obj.key1, get_data)`

Comment: …but what about `.c`? It doesn't need an update?

Comment: nope, that object has x number of keys and only a subset of x needs updating. In this case only a and b. What isn't in there is only if a or b is not empty. But that isn't as important to the flow of the overall function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding your core question. Is this what you're trying to do?

```
var Q = require("q");

var updateFrAsync = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0};

function sampleAsyncCallRandomWait(key) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    setTimeout(function() {
        updateFrAsync[key] = Math.random();
        deferred.resolve();
    }, Math.random());

    return deferred.promise;
}

promises = [sampleAsyncCallRandomWait('a'),sampleAsyncCallRandomWait('c')]

Q.allSettled(promises)
    .then(function (results) {
        console.log(updateFrAsync);
    });
```